# How do you transform multiple columns within one command?

Tags: python, string, pandas, str-replace

Instead of transforming one column at a time, as shown below how would you do both within one command

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.decode('utf-8').str.replace('.', '-')
df['Town'] = df['Town'].str.decode('utf-8').str.replace('.', '-')
```

Comment: `df[['Name','Town']] = df[['Name','Town']].apply(lambda x: x.str.decode()....)`?

Comment: Thanks very much